# Datepicker error with $.inArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am currently working on a function, which should disable weekends and holidays in the jQuery datepicker.

My function looks like this

```
     function calendarDateDisabled(date) {
    //disable saturday (6) and sunday (0)
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if (date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0 || ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1)) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
```

}

The error is the $.inArray. The console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inArray' of undefined`.

The var unavailableDates is defined above the function like this `var unavailableDates  = ["1-5-2015", "25-12-2014","12-12-2014"];`

The function is implemented like this

```
disabled: function(date) {
     return calendarDateDisabled(date);
}
```

Anyone got an idea what's wrong?

*Edit: The syntax of `($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates == -1)` to `($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1)`

Answer (score 1):

Should

```
$.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates == -1)
```

be

```
($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1)
```

?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is the correct syntax and i edited it now. The problem is still there. Could there be any other problem in the code?

Comment: @Yannic `unavailableDates` could be out of scope and make sure that `date` is a date object and not a date string

Comment: Well thanks! That was a mistake aswell. Finally, i solved the problem by reimplementing the jQuery UI. Strange mistake. Tanks for your help though!